# Get first instance for each group in a model

Tags: django, django-orm

So I love django but I keep bumping my head into the same or similar problem.
That is, I have a model A with a FK to another model B, and I want the first model A instance for each model B.

For example, I have the following models:

```py
class Room(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=16, blank=False)

class Event(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False)
    start = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)
    end = models.DateTimeField(blank=False)
    (...)
```

It's basically, each `Room` has `Event`s which have a `start` and `end` time.

**I want to get the *next* `Event` for each `Room` considering *now* - `Q(start__gt=datetime.now())`**

Excepted output (Added):

```py
In [9]: q.values()
Out [9]: <QuerySet [{'id': 13, 'room_id': '0-14', 'start': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 14, 8, 30, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'end': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 14, 10, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'course_id': 'SDis77'}, {'id': 17, 'room_id': '0-21', 'start': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 13, 15, 30, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'end': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 13, 17, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'course_id': 'DDRS14'}, {'id': 31, 'room_id': '0-27', 'start': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 14, 15, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'end': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 14, 16, 30, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'course_id': 'CGra8179577'}, {'id': 41, 'room_id': '1-15', 'start': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 13, 15, 30, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'end': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 13, 17, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'course_id': 'OC12179577'}, {'id': 48, 'room_id': '1-17', 'start': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 15, 15, 30, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'end': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 15, 17, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'course_id': 'SSof7'}, {'id': 52, 'room_id': '1-19', 'start': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 15, 11, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'end': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 15, 12, 30, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'course_id': 'GTI13'}, {'id': 54, 'room_id': '1-27', 'start': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 14, 15, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'end': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 14, 16, 30, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'course_id': 'BD225179577'}, {'id': 57, 'room_id': '1-29', 'start': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 13, 15, 30, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'end': datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 13, 17, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'course_id': 'CSF7'}]>
```

I've tried a lot of things, I don't say everything because I have little experience with `django.db.models.functions` and I don't if that's way

(FIXED) For reference, what I want to do in SQL is :

```sql
SELECT e.* 
FROM api_event AS e 
JOIN (
    SELECT room_id, MIN(start) AS min_start 
    FROM api_event 
    WHERE start > '2020-10-13 15:00:00.000000' 
    GROUP BY room_id
) AS g 
ON e.room_id = g.room_id AND e.start = g.min_start;
```

Which returns this:

```sql
+----+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-------------+
| id | start                      | end                        | room_id | course_id   |
+----+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-------------+
| 13 | 2020-10-14 08:30:00.000000 | 2020-10-14 10:00:00.000000 | 0-14    | SDis77      |
| 17 | 2020-10-13 15:30:00.000000 | 2020-10-13 17:00:00.000000 | 0-21    | DDRS14      |
| 31 | 2020-10-14 15:00:00.000000 | 2020-10-14 16:30:00.000000 | 0-27    | CGra8179577 |
| 41 | 2020-10-13 15:30:00.000000 | 2020-10-13 17:00:00.000000 | 1-15    | OC12179577  |
| 48 | 2020-10-15 15:30:00.000000 | 2020-10-15 17:00:00.000000 | 1-17    | SSof7       |
| 52 | 2020-10-15 11:00:00.000000 | 2020-10-15 12:30:00.000000 | 1-19    | GTI13       |
| 54 | 2020-10-14 15:00:00.000000 | 2020-10-14 16:30:00.000000 | 1-27    | BD225179577 |
| 57 | 2020-10-13 15:30:00.000000 | 2020-10-13 17:00:00.000000 | 1-29    | CSF7        |
+----+----------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-------------+
```

**Note 1**: `VAR_NOW` in this example is equal to `'2020-10-13 15:00:00.000000'`
**Note 2**: I'm not using **Postgres**, I'm using **mysql/mariadb**, so `distinct(arg)` won't help me...

**EDIT**:

- FIXED: So my query in SQL was incorrect because it wouldn't get the first row for each `room` considering the `start`, it would get considering the `id`.
- ADDED: The expected output in python/django

Comment: Please share expected output too.

Comment: If you want to get access Event in the Room instance, just call: `instance.event_set.all()`

Comment: How did you get all the other columns after grouping by room_id (without some aggregating)? I don't think you want to group by here.

Comment: @Popeye Done, added the excepted output in django

Comment: @Strawberry how soo?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat You were right my SQL query was wrong, it wouldn't get the first row for each `room` considering the `start`, it would get considering the `id`. Edited the post and fixed it.

Comment: @Strawberry Tell you what? What do I want? Its on the post...  
"I want to get the next Event for each Room considering now - `Q(start__gt=datetime.now())`"

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question because it could help people even though it's not what I really wanted.

I found a solution but not entirely using Django ORM

```py
now = datetime.now()
q = Event.objects.filter(start__gt=now).order_by('room', 'start')

next_events = []
prev_room = None
for event in q:
    if prev_room != event.room:
        next_events.append(event)
        prev_room = event.room
```

If anyone finds a solution better than this, or in performance or only using Django ORM, let me know.